# adding a local pdf attachment to an email in microsoft crm with vb .net

Tags: vb.net, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm creating an email entity record and trying to download a pdf and attaching to the email using organizationService.

//orgNIZtionaervice to establish connection with crm

```
Dim service As IOrganizationService = Crm_GetOrganizationService()
Dim xrmContext As New CrmServiceContext(service)
Dim filepath = C:\Development\OpenWorks\owreports\PayAdviceAttachments
```

// webclient to download file and storing in local

```
Dim webclient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient
webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
webclient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(My.Settings.WebClientUserName, My.Settings.WebClientPassword)
webclient.DownloadFile(uri, filePath)
```

// creating email

```
Dim email As New Email
email.RegardingObjectId = New EntityReference("account", x)
email.MimeType = "pdf"
email.Subject = "test"
email.To = New ActivityParty() {toParty}
**_emailId** = service.Create(email)
```

To attach an attachment I'm not sure how to attach the file from the local 
Below is the code I tried but it is not working.

```
Dim attachList As List(Of ActivityMimeAttachment) = New List(Of ActivityMimeAttachment)
Dim attach As New ActivityMimeAttachment
attach.ObjectId = New EntityReference(email.EntityLogicalName, **_emailId**)
attach.ObjectTypeCode = email.EntityLogicalName
attach.FileName = filePath
attach.FileName = "test"
service.Create(attach)
```

any help on how to attach the downloaded pdf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add filepath and filename attribute to the Activitymimeattachment entity in CRM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117719/how-to-add-filepath-and-filename-attribute-to-the-activitymimeattachment-entity)

Comment: You won’t find lot of vb.net sample code online, pls refer the linked SO thread for c# equivalent

Comment: @ArunVinoth yes looks like it's working as I see the same file size attached to that email. But the file is not opening from that email, it says unable to open file bcz of its format. I gave mimetype as "pdf" in both email and activitymimeattachment. Am I missing anything?